# how to select a class wrapped in a specific container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'd like to add a margin-top:5px to a subset of classes in the following:

This part is wrong:

```
.af-mh-container-1011.af-row{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

with this html:

```
<div class='af-mh-container-1011'>
    <!-- add to this one -->
    <div class='af-row'>
      here i am
   </div>
</div>

<div class='af-mh-container-not-1011'>
   <div class='af-row'>
      here i am
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use direct descendant combinator: `.af-mh-container-1011 > af-row`

Comment: thx Hashem - that's right. put in answer and I'll accept if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.af-mh-container-1011.af-row` selector tries to match an element having both `af-mh-container-1011` and `af-row` classes.

In order to select the nested child `<div>` having `af-row` class, you could use [direct descendant combinator `A > B`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) as follows:

```
.af-mh-container-1011 > af-row {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Also [`A B`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) would match the nested `B` which is a descendant of `A` element - and not necessarily a direct descendant or a child.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you missed a `space` between the dot -

```
.af-mh-container-1011 .af-row{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/zgf0v0tn/

Comment: ah wierd, you're right = would either work in this case?

Comment: i dont think css has = operator

Comment: = ? why? can you explain?

Comment: sorry, meant to type dash. was just curious as whether that is matching the container / descendent relationship or just some artifact of the simple html.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is applying a margin to an element with both those classes.

You want to target child elements.

Here are a few options:

```
.af-mh-container-1011 > .af-row {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.af-mh-container-1011 .af-row {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.af-mh-container-1011 div {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

All three options will affect your af-row class. The first option is a child selector. This will only affect the direct child. Other divs nested within the .af-row won't be affected. The second option will affect your af-row and any element nested within .af-row with the same class. The last option will affect all divs within af-mh-container-1011. See the example below for further clarification.

```
<div class='af-mh-container-1011'>
    <div class='af-row'>
        <div class='af-row'>
            This nested element is unaffected by a child selector (first option) but is affected by a decendant selector (second option). It is also affected by the 3rd option.
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```